# n-Tree printing specific path: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, class, oop, tree

I am trying to print a specific path between the node and leaf. I have created a class n-tree (tree to have multiple n-children) but when I run my function, it tells me

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'
```

This is my code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def add_child(self, obj):
        self.children.append(obj)

def hasPath(root, arr, x):
    if (not root):
        return False

    arr.append(root.data)

    if(root.data == x):
        return True

    if(hasPath(root.left, arr, x) or hasPath(root.right, arr, x)):
        return True

    arr.pop(-1)
    return False

def printPath(root, x):

    arr = []

    if(hasPath(root, arr, x)):
        for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
            print(arr[i], end = "->")
        print(arr[len(arr) - 1])

    else:
        return []
```

I am still a beginner at this so I don't really understand how classes work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which function do you run that you get the error message? Show the code which fails

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, unless there is a good reason not to do so.

Comment: the printPath function fails. Also, it worth noting that I am using is a list of lists as the node

Comment: Show the code that calls `printPath`